# Animated progress bar text display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(The code that is on my website will be pasted below)
I have just ripped this code out of the internet [LINK](http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery) and I was wondering if someone could help me a little bit. There is a small x% at the end display the percentage (x being the number). Is there any way that I could make this appear in the middle of the progress bar, instead of at the end and also change the font of the text? Once it is full that the x% would disappear? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

```js
function progressBar(percent, $element) {
 var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
 $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "%&nbsp;");
}
```

```css
#progressBar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color: #292929;
}

#progressBar div {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #CC6600;
}

.pbar {
 background: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #AAA;
 overflow: hidden;  
}
.pbar div {
 background-image: url(pbar.gif);
 border-right: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/progressbar.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="progressBar" class="pbar"><div></div></div>
<script>
 progressBar(23, $('#progressBar'));
</script>
```

[image: Gif for background] Here is the gif for the background

Comment: change the text-align:right; in #progressBar div to text-align:center; and also change the css for that element to contain your font preferences

Comment: @DRGA Thank you, I had actually tried the font-family before and that didn't seem to work. I missed the text-align the first time though, but this time it did work (both of them) thanks! Not sure why the font-family didn't work the first time, but oh well it works now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a shortcut and use bootstrap progress bars.

If you want to animate it. Use the width property

```js
var w = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  w = w % 100 + 10;

  $('#animate').width(w + '%').text(w + '%')
}, 1000);
```

```css
.progress-bar-purple {
  background-color: purple !important;
  font-size: 24px !important;
  line-height: 240px !important;
  font-family: "Times New Roman"
}
.progress.tall {
  min-height: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.progress-bar-orange {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div id='animate' class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div id='animate' class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-orange active" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress tall">
  <div id='animate' class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-purple active" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks nice, but how can I customise them for example using my own css? Width, Height, Background colour, Bar colour, Font, Font colour etc.?

Comment: Edited answer for custom bars