# progress bar text not showing

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

This meteor client code tries to set a text in the centre of the progress bar but the text is not showing on the screen though it is showing in the inspection panel. Tried on Chrome and Safari for no avail. 
 Any suggestions how to fix this? thx

```
lib = (function () {
  return Object.freeze({
    'clickInfo': function () {
        Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
          let bar = document.getElementById('bar');
          bar.style.visibility = 'visible';
          lib.progressBarStart(bar);
        }, 50);

    },
    'progressBarStart': function (bar) {
      if (bar && bar.value < 70) {
        if (Session.get('inProgress')) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            bar = document.getElementById('bar'); 
            lib.progressBarStart(bar);
          }, 1000);
          bar.value += 1;
        }
      } else if (Session.get('inProgress')) {
        bar.innerHTML = 'Result will be emailed'; // <== text failed to show
      }
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
#bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<progress id="bar" value="0" max="70"></progress>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781763/5047454 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:before` pseudo element in CSS to show the text.
I Hope this helps you

```
progress::before {
  content: 'Result will be emailed';
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
}
```

helpful fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/96z0gwv7/1/

Jquery:

```
$('#bar').addClass('done');
```

Css:

```
progress.done::before{
  content: 'Result will be emailed';
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
}
```

Comment: then `$('#bar').addClass('progress:before');` instead of `bar.innerHTML = 'Result will be emailed';` did not work

Comment: well. as you notice in my JS code. It only needs to show up at a certain time only.

Comment: I applied the edits as stated but still not fixed. Not sure why.

Comment: Check the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969725/progress-bar-text?rq=1
Hope this gives you an idea

Answer (score 1):

Progress bars are not supposed to show any text. I'd recommend to add another element (`<div>` for example) and show it in place of (or atop of) progress bar.

Comment: Could you give the JS code where a `p` element can be placed on top of the bar with the text in the center of it? or in its place as you suggested?